# How can I create a drop down menu within a table?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-table, hyperlink

I have a single-row table with links in each cell (code below). I would like to add a dropdown menu to each link so that people can navigate directly to items within the main linked paged. For example, the main link might take you to "University Library," and I would like things like "Hours" or "Databases" to show up as links in a dropdown that appears when you hover over "University Library." Ideas?

```
<style>
.menubar {font-size: 20px; color:#00285b; font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; background-color:#e8eced;}

table, td, th {
border: 0px; }

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;}

th {
width:auto
padding:50px}
</style>

<table class="menubar">
<tr>

<th><a href='http://www.regent.edu/lawlibrary/' target="_blank">Law Library Home </a></th>
<th><a href='http://libguides.regent.edu/' target="_blank">Research Tools</a></th>
<th><a href='http://libguides.regent.edu/lawabout' target="_blank">About the Library</a></th>
<th><a href='https://library.regent.edu/patroninfo' target="_blank">My Account</a></th>
<th><a href='http://www.regent.edu/lib' target="_blank">University Library</a></th>
<th><a href='https://www.regent.edu/school-of-law/' target="_blank">Law School</a></th>
<th><a href='http://www.regent.edu' target="_blank">Regent Home</a></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use a model similar to this Pen - https://codepen.io/GlenTheEskimo/pen/WYEbbw

Comment: Why does it need to be in a table? It's not best practice to use tables for controlling layout.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a table. It was originally a list, but i was having trouble controlling its position and formatting when I changed other things on the page (somebody else wrote the code, and it was strange). I'm more familiar with tables. If you have a better solution that would be fine.

Comment: I'll try Glen's solution, too.

Comment: Thanks Glen Carpenter! In the spirit of information sharing, this is the final product: